React Native Facebook authentication Issue
Im getting the error below when I use the fb credentials which is used in developer account am able to login, but not with others, but  my app is live in fb developer and i have done business verification as well, could anyone suggest me what other changes should i need to make
Error: "App not active: This app is not currently accessible and the app developer is aware of the issue. You will be able to log in when the app is reactivated."

import { useAppSelector } from '@components/redux/hooks';
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { View, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { LoginManager, AccessToken, GraphRequest, GraphRequestManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
import { BASE_URL } from 'src/helpers/Config';



const FacebookAuth = () => {
  const { loading, userData } = useAppSelector((state) => state.users);
  console.log(userData, "facebook user")
  const FacebookLogin = async () => {

    try {

      const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile']);
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        console.log('Facebook login cancelled.');
      } else {
        const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (data) {
          console.log(data, "data from facebook")
          console.log('Facebook access token:', data.accessToken.toString());
          let fbToken = data.accessToken.toString()
          let userId = userData?._id

          await axios.patch(`${BASE_URL}updateFacebookData?_id=${userId}`, {
            // Assuming user_id is defined somewhere in your component
            facebook_Token: fbToken,
            // userFacebookInfo:data
          }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          });

          const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
            '/me',
            {
              accessToken: data.accessToken,
              parameters: {
                fields: {
                  string: 'email,name,first_name,last_name'
                }
              }
            },
            async (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data: ', error);
              } else {
                console.log('User data: ', result);
                let obj = { ...data, ...result }
                await axios.patch(`${BASE_URL}updateFacebookData?_id=${userId}`, {
                  // Assuming user_id is defined somewhere in your component
                  // facebook_Token:fbToken,
                  userFacebookInfo: obj
                }).then((res) => {
                  console.log(res)
                }).catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err)
                });
              }
            }
          );

          new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Facebook login error:', error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={FacebookLogin} style={{ alignItems: "center" }}><Text style={{ color: "#0073b1", textAlign: "center" }}>Link Your Facebook</Text></TouchableOpacity>

      {/* style={{color:"#0073b1",textAlign:"center"}} */}
      {/* <Button title="Link Your Facebook" onPress={FacebookLogin} /> */}
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },
  loading: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default FacebookAuth;


This question is similar to: app not active: This app is not currently accessible and the app developer is aware of the issue. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
